# Docker Debian Jessie: Can't find /var/log/syslog

Tags: debian, cron, logs, docker

I'm building on top of a [Postgres Docker container](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/tree/master/puppetdb-postgres) which has cron implemented on top of Debian Jessie:

For debugging I want to look at the logs which I'm expecting to be at `/var/log/syslog`, but I don't have syslog on the system.

Would I need to turn on logging manually with a Debian Jessie Docker container?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to install `rsyslog` inside the container. You could do this in `dockerfile`.

Example of simplest `dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get install -q -y rsyslog
CMD ["sh", "-c", "service rsyslog start ; tail -f /dev/null"]
```