# Docker Debian, getting some specific syslog in the docker container log

Tags: debian, logs, docker, syslog

I have been installing SSH in the Debian Docker. Since I wanted to have some extra log, I also installed the Rsyslog as described in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395841/docker-debian-jessie-cant-find-var-log-syslog).

Result was that some extra logs are created e.g. `auth.log` (to see who logged in). To look into this log, I have to install `vi` or `nano` in the container and look at it in the container.

Question is now: can I somehow add this `auth.log` or other logs to the Docker log? So I can just look at the log in Portainer, instead of having to go in the console mode of the container?

Comment: What you're asking for is called combining logs - this is discouraged - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626579/is-there-a-way-to-combine-docker-images-into-1-container.

Comment: The installation of SSH in your Docker container is also something that's discouraged. Is your Dockerfile somewhere that we could take a look at it?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your info. I am not combining logs. At this moment the debian docker is not giving me any log at all.... 
I am installing this SSH so I can have a very specific SFTP server, which serves my purposes (installing is done in the dockerfile). I am not using it to log into the container, as is discouraged. My question is: how can I add any log into the docker log. I do not have the dockerfile somewhere.